# IE9 decode error on HTML5 video of mp4 file

Tags: html, video, internet-explorer-9, mp4, codec

I write a html5 page, the source is as fllows:

```
<!doctype html5>
....
<video id="vdemo1" controls  width="440" height="248">
  <source src='http://mysite.com/demo.webm' type='video/webm'>
  <source src='http://mysite.com/demo.mp4' type='video/mp4'>
  // fallback codes
</video>
```

the output of video tag is an empty black box. By following the instruction on this url:[HTML5 Video not working in IE9 - Some tips to debug](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/thebeebs/archive/2011/07/20/html5-video-not-working-in-ie9-some-tips-to-debug.aspx), it shows a MEDIA_ERR_DECODE error code. However, I can right click on the empty viewport and choose 'play' item but nothing  appears in viewport. After right clck and choose 'save' to save mp4 file to local hd, it can be played well under OS. I even change video src to local file but it doesn't help!

Does IE9 lose the mp4 codec ability ( I'm sure the mp4 is encoded in H.264)? How can I regain the ability?

=======
edit @ 2012/10/9

There's a strange thing happened. I never run Windows media player before and after I run it 1st time, if source of video tag is local file, it can be playbacked. But if remote url, then it won't. Can anyone see why?

Comment: New questions should not be appended to other questions... and you should rate answers to your existing questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Re-sort the sources - put mp4 on top!
2. Check if your server sends the correct mime type (video/mp4) for your mp4.

Both can break playback...

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes I've seen IE9 have trouble playing videos encoded with [B-Frames](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B_frames#Bi-directional_predicted_frames.2Fslices_.28B-frames.2Fslices.29). Try encoding your video without them. You can do this with ffmpeg by adding the option "-bf 0" to the command line.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, Internet Explorer throws a decode error (MEDIA_ERR_DECODE - An error has occurred in the decoding of the media resource, after the resource was established to be usable) and is unable to play videos with dimensions that are not evenly divisible by 16.
  For example, it may perfectly play a video that is 960x400 ( 960 % 16 == 0 and 400 % 16 == 0 ), but when reducing the dimensions by half (480x200) it will not play ( 480 % 16 == 0 but 200 % 16 != 0 ).

One way to get around this is to enclose the re-sized video in an area with known good geometry, and then pad out the remaining area with black bars to avoid distorting the aspect ratio.
  To do this, we used the following code adapted from a different SO answer that I can't seem to track down right now: `-vf "scale=iw*min(640/iw\,480/ih):ih*min(640/iw\,480/ih),pad=640:480:(640-iw)/2:(480-ih)/2"`.